# I am having trouble to display the json variables from jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

- The names are not displaying in the dropdown box of autocomplete
- And how can I assign each variable to a specific textbox when I get the response

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="id" />
<input type="text" id="tel" />
<script> $("#name").autocomplete({ source: "php/company.php" });  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
$term = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

$sql = "select ID,NAME,TEL from COMPANY where NAME like '%$term%' order by NAME";
$result = mysql_query($sql, DBCONN) or die ("<br>MySQL Error: " . mysql_error(DBCONN));
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $row_set = array( 
                "label" => $row['NAME'], 
                "id" => $row['ID'],
                "tell" => $row['TEL'] );
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

FIREBUG JSON RESPONSE:

```
{"label":"MacDonald","id":"1","tel":"1-800-4444"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RTFM](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

> The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two
>   variants:
>
> - An Array of Strings:
> - An Array of Objects with label and value properties

Your json response is not really an Array, is it? Also you can only update your autocompletion for one field.

```
$("#name").autocomplete({ source: function callback(term, autocomplete) {
    $.getJSON("php/company.php?term="+term, function(data) {
        // do the magic here: extract an option array from your data, e.g.
        var arrayOfStrings = data.names;
        autocomplete(arrayOfStrings);
    });
});
```

I don't understand what you want to do with the other data, when searching your DB for a specific name you won't be able to autocomplete the phone number input field, will you?

---

EDIT: Your problem is that your json response currently does output the last of the matching names as an Object. If you instead would return an Array, the autocomplete feature would be useful. Several bugs fixed:

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_GET["term"]));

$sql = "select ID,NAME,TEL from COMPANY where NAME like '%$term%' order by NAME";
$result = mysql_query($sql, DBCONN) or die ("{\"error\":\"" . mysql_error(DBCONN) . "\"}");
$output = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row_set = array( 
        "label" => $row['NAME'], 
        "value" => $row['NAME'], 
        "id" => $row['ID'],
        "tell" => $row['TEL'] );
    $output[] = $row_set;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

If you make it a custom callback function with adjusted ajax calls (see above), you can now check for `data.error` before trying to extract an array.

Now you may want to play with custom item displays, focus and select events. For example with

- [`.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) (see source of linked example) you can display custom list items
- on [`.autocomplete({focus:...})`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-focus) you may set #id and #tel to their corresponding values and
- on [`.autocomplete({select:...})`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) you may freeze #id and #tel (disable the inputs)

Comment: When I get the company name I would like to get the telephone number also to display it in the textbox of telephone

Comment: The sense of autocomplete is to get more than only one (company) name - what do you want to do with multiple ids / phone numbers?

Comment: I want to pass the company's telephone and id to other inputss. Tnxx for ur answer was helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

By default the plugin expects an array of strings, not objects.

You need to use [custom data rendering](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data).

```
$("#name").autocomplete({
        ....
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#name" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        }
        ....
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.id + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Comment: I changed my code but still nothing happens, maybe the error is in my php response??

`$("input#autocomplete")
 .autocomplete({ 
  source: "php/company.php",
  minLength: 0,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
   $( "#autocomplete" ).val( ui.item.label );
   return false;
  }, 
  
  select: function( event, ui ) {
   $( "#autocomplete" ).val( ui.item.label );

   return false;
  }  
 })
 .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li></li>" )
   .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
   .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
   .appendTo( ul );
 };`